Custom cursor doesn't work over other applications
I saw the post about this problem but it hasn't changed anything.
So, I want to use the oreo orange cursor and it works, but only over Ubuntu programs (over other apps such as Firefox or Steam I see default DMZ-White cursor. It is toggles through windows). I also tried different cursors, but the problem still the same.
(this commands changed nothing:

flatpak --user override --filesystem=/home/$USER/.icons/:ro
flatpak --user override --filesystem=/usr/share/icons/:ro).

I have Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. Hope someone could help me.

does this itsFOSS article help?

@graham unfortunately, both ways through terminal and GUI Flatseal from the article didn't work. I did everything according to the instructions. idk what's wrong
